# c++ typedef and subclassing

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I am having a bit of trouble with a c++ class that I am trying to implement.

I subclass `std::vector<T>` but I can't get the iterator. Here's my sample code:

This line

```
MyPairList::iterator Item = this->begin();
```

I can't get the iterator to my template class.

How can I fix this and why exactly is it happening because right now I am totally at a loss. Also this is all described in my .h file, no .cpp file.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

    template<typename T>
    class MyPairList : public vector<T>
    {
    public:
        void Form()
        {
            _idColl.clear();
            _nameColl.clear();


            MyPairList::iterator Item = this->begin();
            for ( ; Item != this->end() ;  ++Item)
            {
                _idColl.insert(make_pair( (*Item)->ID, (*Item) ));
                _nameColl.insert(make_pair( (*Item)->Name, (*Item) ));
            }
        }

        T Lookup(int pID)
        {
            if (_idColl.find(pID) != _idColl.end())
            {
                return _idColl[pID];
            }

            return T();
        }

        T Lookup(const string &pName)
        {
            if (_nameColl.find(pName) != _nameColl.end())
            {
                return _nameColl[pName];
            }

            return T();
        }

        MyPairList()
        {
        }

    private:
        unordered_map<int, T> _idColl;
        unordered_map<string, T> _nameColl;
    };
```

Comment: can you paste the code where you use MyPairList. BTW, inheriting vector is not a good idea.

Comment: This is a poster child for using `auto`. All you need is `auto Item = this->begin();`

Comment: @XiaotianPei I am parsing xml data each iteration through the xml I create one of the above class and push a reference to the collections, one by name with it's associated object and one by id with that one's associated object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
MyPairList::iterator Item = this->begin();
```

use

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator Item = this->begin();
```

Another option is to create type aliases.

```
using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
using const_iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;
```

Then, you can use:

```
iterator Item = this->begin();
```

Comment: ```typename std::vector<T>::iterator Item = this->begin();```

Comment: wow you guys are amazing, I chose your answer because it's more detailed and provide a few different ways to solve the problem.

Comment: You could also just have `using typename std::vector<T>::iterator`

Comment: @RyanHaining, yes, that's also another option.

Comment: `typename MyPairList::iterator Item = this->begin();` works, there's no need to name the base class. Also `auto Item = this->begin();`

Answer (score 0):

```
typename MyPairList::iterator Item = this->begin();
```